# How can I pass rails helper methods to a view using ActionView::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ActionView::Base to render views in my current rails project, instead of ApplicationController. So far this has gone smoothly, but now I need a way to access helper methods from views rendered in this fashion. The exact code I am using to render views looks like this:

```
action_view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
action_view.render(file: "example/path", locals: { foo: 1, bar: "hello world" })
```

Is there any way to pass custom helper methods from the helpers folder to a view being rendered in this fashion?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `send` to include the helpers you need

```
action_view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
action_view.class.send(:include, ApplicationHelper)
action_view.render(file: "example/path", locals: { foo: 1, bar: "hello world" })
```